# RShiny and Modules output. Object of type environment is not subsettable

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

Dear people of sackoverflow,

I am currently trying to create an app where a user can upload a dataset from various sources. I tried to isolate the code for the upload in a separate Shiny module. However, R throws an error saying that an environment object is not subsettable. I am fairly new to shiny so would appreciate any advice regarding the use of modules too. :)

```
library(shiny)

fileInputUI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fileInput(
    inputId = ns("file"), 
    label = "Select a file"
  )
  
}

fileInputServer <- function(id){
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    
    dataset <- reactive({
      
      req(input$file)
      
      # Get file extension and datapath      
      ext <- tools::file_ext(input$file$name)
      datapath <- input$file$datapath
      
      # Need reactive values to store input data in
      read_data_options <- reactiveValues()
      
      read_data_options$sep <- NULL
      
      if(ext == "csv"){
        
        choices_sep <- c(",", ";", "", "\\t")
        names(choices_sep) <- c("Comma (,)", "Semicolon (;)", "White space ( )", "Tab separated (\\t)")
        
        showModal(
          ui = modalDialog(
            selectInput(
              inputId = NS(id, "sep"), 
              label = "Which separator is used for your data",
              choices = names(choices_sep),
              selected = ""
            ),
            # Input is required so no dismiss button
            footer = tagList(
              modalButton("Dismiss"),
              actionButton(
                inputId = NS(id, "submit_csv"), 
                label = "Submit")
            ),
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
        
        # Set input value from submit button
        observeEvent(
          eventExpr = input$submit_csv, 
          handlerExpr = {
            
            
            read_data_options$sep <- choices_sep[input$sep]
            removeModal()
            
            read.csv(
              file = datapath,
              sep = read_data_options$sep
            )
          }
        )
        
      } else {
        
        NULL
        
      }
      
    })
    
    dataset
    
  })
  
}

# Shiny App
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInputUI("test"),
  
  tableOutput("head_data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dataset <- fileInputServer("test")
  
  output$head_data <- renderTable(head(dataset()))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I used modalDialog because I figured it to be the simplest approach to asking users about additional inputs to the read function for example the separator in case of read.csv or the startRow for read.xlsx etc.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get any error - but I also don't see anything else happen after uploading a dataset. Can you confirm what behaviour you want to see, and check that your code replicates the problems you see in a new environment?

Comment: Hm that's odd. I get the error message that an object of type environment is not subsettable. The stacktrace points to the renderTable function. As a result I want to have the head of the dataframe rendered and dataset as a reactive. Thanks for your reply